# if i delete photos on my camera roll on my iphone will it delete the photos on photo stream on my macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, iphone, photo-stream

If I delete photos on my camera roll on my iphone 4s will it delete the photos on photo stream on my macbook pro?

Answer (score 5):

It shouldn't. The Camera Roll and your Photo Stream "live" in separate places.

I just did a test with this. I placed the same photo in both the Photo Stream and the Camera Roll and then deleted the copy from the Camera Roll. The one in the Photo Stream stayed in place.

Comment: Just make sure you're at the right place... If you have the setting to send your photos to iCloud automatically, you should get them in both, if I remember correctly and it can be misleading.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little confusing, unfortunately, especially because if you only have a photo in the Photo Stream album and you delete it deletes it from every Photo Stream album on every device. Can be disastrous if you don't have a copy saved elsewhere.

Comment: But if only in camera roll it shouldn't affect other devices, right?